# Use my physical location or office address on resume when working remotely?

Tags: resume, telecommute

I'm working remotely for some company headquartered in city X, but I work in city Y.  When I list this job on a resume, should I list it under

ACME Inc, city X

or

ACME Inc, city Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put where YOU are, not the company head office.  Or both.

You could put:

> ACME Inc, city Y (Head Office city X)

If you aren't in X, regardless of where you are remoting *to*.  It's misleading otherwise, especially if it's in another country.  There are a couple of good reasons for stating your physical location instead:

- It could lead to the assumption of working visas for somewhere you don't actually have.
- If asked where in city X you are living, you then have to backtrack and state that you actually live in city Y and work remotely to ACME Inc.  It's not necessarily a red flag to me as a hiring manager, but it's confusing.

So best to be up front about where you are.  Realistically, the location of the office you are remoting *to* is kind of irrelevant beyond letting any future employers know what market you may be servicing.

Comment: Resume is personal business anyway, unless you're preparing it for company-internal job seeking.  Personal address is clearly the right answer.